# Filter an array object by a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the easiest way to do the following task ? Many thanks

```
obj = [ 
    { 'uniqueID' : "B111222", "Fees" : 111}, 
    { 'uniqueID' : "B222111", "Fees" : 222}, 
    { 'uniqueID' : "B333111", "Fees" : 333}
]


unwanted = [ "B111222", "B222111"]
```

Outcomes

```
>>>> [{'uniqueID': 'B333111', 'Fees': 333}]
```

Comment: what have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: most online answers just showing by filtering a criteria/string/value only
e.g. 
filter(lambda x: x.yyy == "zzzz", arr)
or
[x for x in arr if x.yyy == "zzzz"]

I have no ideas how to write a line of code by filtering multiple string/values/criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comprehension approach will work:

```
obj = [ 
    { 'uniqueID' : "B111222", "Fees" : 111}, 
    { 'uniqueID' : "B222111", "Fees" : 222}, 
    { 'uniqueID' : "B333111", "Fees" : 333}
]

unwanted = [ "B111222", "B222111"]

filtered = [d for d in obj if d['uniqueID'] not in unwanted]

print(filtered)
```

> [{'uniqueID': 'B333111', 'Fees': 333}]

If the dictionaries in `obj` are not guaranteed to have a `uniqueID`, then some additional error checking will be necessary.

```
filtered = [d for d in obj if 'uniqueID' in d.keys() 
            and d['uniqueID'] not in unwanted]
```

Comment: great !! I keep thinking != syntax in looping.....quite a beginner in python ///▽///

Comment: @peekaboo Sometimes large list comprehensions can make things unreadable, but in this case, I think it shows the intent better and is readable.